# Is it possible to install PHP 5 and MySQL on Apache Tomcat 6.0.32 WITHOUT Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: php, apache, jsp, tomcat, webserver

There's a webserver which serves dynamic JSP contents, but we would like to serve some PHP contents too.
**Is it possible to install PHP 5 and MySQL on Apache Tomcat 6.0.32 WITHOUT** stopping the service of current contents, uninstalling Tomcat, **installing the Apache HTTP Server** (via [AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/), [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or something similar which installs PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin too with just some simple clicks), and after that, configuring the [Apache Tomcat Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html)?

Currently I don't have the opportunity to configure the mentioned "target" webserver, but I installed Tomcat on my local machine, so with my own webserver I can try doing anything suggested.

I know there are lots of questions related to the topic even on stackoverflow, but none of them answered my question.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Off topic -- belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer: maybe you're right, sorry for that. :( But I thought many programmers here on stackoverflow could have met similar problems to mine. :) Thanks for your understanding, I'll take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) or [JSR223 + PHP-bridge](http://blogs.oracle.com/kchung/entry/native_php_in_glassfish_with) to read/parse/run PHP files using Java.

As to MySQL, as being just a simple and standalone DB server, it doesn't require a specific webserver. MySQL totally doesn't care wat webserver you're running. Just install and configure it the usual way.

Oh, please note that the Apache Tomcat Connector requires Apache HTTPD server. So if you don't want to install Apache HTTPD, then the Tomcat Connector is worthless to you.

Comment: finally I didn't have enough time to try that, but I chose the other solution, which seems much simpler: to install XAMPP with Tomcat Add-On, which "connects" Tomcat to Apache HTTP Server; but I'm sure your solution works (even if I didn't have a chance (and time) to try it), that's why I accepted it. Thanks. BUT I would be glad if you could help me in the further steps to configure Apache HTTP Server + Tomcat Server the appropriate way: http://serverfault.com/questions/301224/xampp-with-tomcat-add-on-how-to-configure-it-to-serve-java-or-php-contents-depe . Thanks for that in advance too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat supports [CGI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cgi-howto.html) so why not install php5-cgi?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's possible to install Apache Tomcat without HTTPD, but I can answer your question partially:

By default, it's not possible. I don't know why, but package-installers (I used YUM at EC2) require you to install HTTPD too as a dependency of PHP. So if your package-installer requires this too, you need to build PHP from source (which isn't very hard though).  **Edit:** I'm using FastCGI, 'just' PHP might not work, but it would surprise me though. (FastCGI works since, just like MySQL, you can install PHP-FastCGI on a separate server).

MySQL is fully independant. Since you can also install it on a separate server (db-server) without PHP and a HTTP-server, it's possible to install MySQL without HTTPD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! (You've got a vote-up too. :)) Finally I chose the other solution to install Apache HTTP Server first via XAMPP, and than install Tomcat through an add-on. But it would be great if you could also help me configuring that the appropriate way: http://serverfault.com/questions/301224/xampp-with-tomcat-add-on-how-to-configure-it-to-serve-java-or-php-contents-depe . Thanks in advance. :)